# Best books and tutorials on distribution theory

Tags: distributions, references

I am looking for books or tutorials to self study distributions and their properties.
I know some basic about statistics and statistical inference in general, but I would like to learn more about distribution theory in particular, e.g. how distributions relates to one another and how to see, which distribution occurs by adding/subtracting/dividing etc. various kinds of distributions.

I know similar questions exists, but are of older dates, hence I ask again.

All suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many books on the topic *Statistical Distributions*, see this [stored search](https://www.bookdepository.com/search?searchTerm=statistical+distributions&search=Find+book) which gives many titles on a spectrum from very applied (or "cookbook") to more theoretical. Look through the list!

A theoretical book  I like is [Elements of Distribution Theory](https://www.bookdepository.com/Elements-Distribution-Theory-Thomas-Severini/9781107630734?ref=grid-view&qid=1612987849726&sr=1-1) by  Thomas A. Severini, but it builds on calculus and linear algebra. In my first link there is offerings at various levels!

Answer (score 4):

There’s no such a thing as a “distribution theory”. There’s probability theory and calculus that explain this. Distributions are just functions. Their relations are just relations between mathematical functions.

If you are looking for a cheatsheet with common distributions, you can just study carefully the [articles on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions).